# How to show subviews one by one with delay on swift

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, delay

first of all, I have just started to work on swift.

I am creating image views in for loop and trying to show them one by one with some delays. I am trying to achieve this in viewDidAppear function, however all the image views are shown all together without any delays even i use below function:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

var i = 1

    var backgroundQueue:dispatch_queue_t =  dispatch_queue_create("SerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    for award in (awards){

        //dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, { () -> () in

            var awardView = AwardView(imageName: award, sideLength: awardSize)

            var pointX: CGFloat = xOffset + CGFloat(i-1) * (awardSize + COIN_MARGIN)
            var pointY: CGFloat = yOffset

            awardView.center = CGPointMake( pointX, pointY)

            //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in

                self.pointsContainerView.addSubview(awardView)

                audioController.playEffect(SOUND_DING)
            //})

        //});

        i++
    }
```

I am not sure whether i am trying to do this in correct function (viewDidAppear).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to load subviews in sequence. This runs thread in background serially and once it get the UIView it updates screen and waits for a second before loading next UIView.
 You can try this way I hope it helps

```
var awards:NSArray=NSArray(objects: "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg")
    var x:CGFloat=10.00
    var y:CGFloat=100.00
    var backgroundQueue:dispatch_queue_t =  dispatch_queue_create("SerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    for award in awards{
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, { () -> () in
        // do some task

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in

            var image:UIImage=UIImage(named: award as String)!
            var awardView :UIImageView = UIImageView(image:image)
            awardView.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 300, 400);
            self.view.addSubview(awardView);
             x=x+310.00;

        })
        sleep(1);

    });

}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but when i use your suggestion, subviews are not displaying on the main view. 

When i comment the queue code, it shows on the main view but all of them at once, not sequential.

Comment: what is awards is this array? And I don't see u have set frame for UIView? self.pointsContainerView is this your mainView. I guess you are not able to see subviews because you have not set subviews frame

Comment: I am setting frame in AwardView class as below so i think it is not about frame.

self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sideLength, height: sideLength)

Comment: This way  
self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sideLength, height: sideLength) all subViews will be overlapped with each other. You will be able to see the last one. so you need to change x and y when you are enumerating in loop

Comment: I am sorry, i updated my question. Since it was not full of my code, I think it did mislead you. Please have a look again, i am already setting frame in AwardView class and then setting center coordinates of it in loop. 

When i run this code, i can see the imageviews but when i uncomment queue code which you suggested, i can not see any of them. 

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Let me compile something similar to this then I will update. Your idea is to load UIImageView after every one second on gridview layout

Comment: Yes exactly. My idea is like when user answers the question correctly, showing correct answer icon, then adding 3 coins to the user. Then showing Bonus icon if he finished on time,  and adding 3 more coins to the user. and so on.. So user can easily understand how many coins he got and why.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a basic example you can modify your code accordingly

Comment: Thank you buddy, it is working like a charm. You are great. your first suggestion was also working, but i think maybe the problem was i was not defining variables in the scope of dispatch_async, after defining everything inside the scope, it worked.